# Move constructor with if-statement but copy constructor with ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

*Context:* I was making experiments to learn when does gcc perform [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), and if not, when does it use move semantics. My version of gcc is `g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)`.

*Question:* I have a function that returns a `Foo` by value. Compiler cannot perform RVO because there are two possible named return values. When I use the ternary operator to select which of `Foo` to return, then I need to explicitly call `std::move` to avoid the copy. I do not need the `std::move` when using an if statement. Why the discrepancy?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    std::string s;
    Foo()                                        { cout << "Foo()\n"; }
    ~Foo()                                       { cout << "~Foo()\n"; }
    Foo(const Foo& other)     : s(other.s)       { cout << "Foo(const Foo&)\n"; }
    Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept : s(move(other.s)) { cout << "Foo(Foo&&)\n"; }
};

Foo makeFooIf(bool which) {
    Foo foo1; foo1.s = "Hello, World1!";
    Foo foo2; foo2.s = "Hello, World2!";
    if (which) return foo1;
    else       return foo2;
}

Foo makeFooTernary(bool which) {
    Foo foo1; foo1.s = "Hello, World1!";
    Foo foo2; foo2.s = "Hello, World2!";
    return which ? foo1 : foo2;
}

Foo makeFooTernaryMove(bool which) {
    Foo foo1; foo1.s = "Hello, World1!";
    Foo foo2; foo2.s = "Hello, World2!";
    return which ? move(foo1) : move(foo2);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "----- makeFooIf -----\n";
    Foo fooIf = makeFooIf(true);
    cout << fooIf.s << endl;

    cout << "\n----- makeFooTernary -----\n";
    Foo fooTernary = makeFooTernary(true);
    cout << fooTernary.s << endl;

    cout << "\n----- makeFooTernaryMove -----\n";
    Foo fooTernaryMove = makeFooTernaryMove(true);
    cout << fooTernaryMove.s << endl;

    cout << "\n----- Cleanup -----\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
----- makeFooIf -----
Foo()
Foo()
Foo(Foo&&)
~Foo()
~Foo()
Hello, World1!

----- makeFooTernary -----
Foo()
Foo()
Foo(const Foo&)
~Foo()
~Foo()
Hello, World1!

----- makeFooTernaryMove -----
Foo()
Foo()
Foo(Foo&&)
~Foo()
~Foo()
Hello, World1!

----- Cleanup -----
~Foo()
~Foo()
~Foo()
```

Comment: there is special wording for `return name-of-local;` that makes a `move` implicit there.

Comment: @sp2danny Thx. According to the standard, would a smarter compiler be *allowed* to implicitly `move` in the case of the ternary operator. Or is the standard saying something like "If the return statement is of the form `return name-of-local`, you must implicitly move, and otherwise, you must not implicitly move`? I guess I can have a look myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implicit move in certain situations:

**§12.8.32**

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but
>   not for an exception-declaration, and the object to be copied is
>   designated by an lvalue, or when the **expression in a return statement**
>   is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression **that names an object** with
>   automatic storage duration **declared in the body** or
>   parameter-declaration-clause of the **innermost enclosing function** or
>   lambda-expression, overload resolution to select the constructor for
>   the copy is first performed **as if** the object were designated by an
>   **rvalue**. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed,
>   or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is
>   not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified),
>   overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an
>   lvalue.

My bolding

Comment: Thx! I was looking through the standard but couldn't find the appopriate clause, I'm not used to this at all. So this seems to explain why the if-version works as it works. In the case of the ternary operator, then I suppose that the expression `which ? foo1 : foo2` is first evaluated (which causes a copy, returning an unnamed temporary), and then the copy from this temporary to the `fooTernary` is elided by the compiler by performing RVO. Does that sound right?

Comment: @boris no, `?` on two identical types of value creates no copies.

Comment: @Yakk Thnks, you're right, if I do `std::move(which ? foo1 : foo2)`, there is no copy happening as well! :)